# TCP server ReadAsync worth then EndRead

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, tcpserver

Usually I can find asnwer on this or other web-sites, documentation. But now i can't anderstand...
I have two versions of Code for TCP server, (NetworkSteam read).

With ReadAsync:

```
public async Task StartWorkAsync(TcpClient Modem, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            using (Modem)
            {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    var steam = Modem.GetStream();
                    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested && !StopAllWorkFoClients.WaitOne(0))
                    {
                        var amountReadTask = steam.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, ct);
                        var amountRead = await amountReadTask.ConfigureAwait(false);

                        if (amountReadTask.IsFaulted || amountReadTask.IsCanceled)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error:IsFaulted||IsCanceled");
                            break;
                        }
                        await WorkOnReceiveModemData(buf.Take(amountRead).ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
            }
        }
```

And with BeginRead, EndRead:

```
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        public void StartWork(TcpClient Modem)
        {
            var steam = Modem.GetStream();
            var x = steam.BeginRead(buf, 0, buf.Length, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveDataAsync), (object)steam);
        }

        public void ReceiveDataAsync(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream x = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;//(((Tuple<object,object>)ar.AsyncState).Item1);

                try
                {
                    bytesread += x.EndRead(ar);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                var timeout = 0;
                var bytesbefore = bytesread;
                x.ReadTimeout = 50;
                while (bytesread < _BYTESBUFFERCOUNT)
                {
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                    if (x.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        var ii = x.Read(bufzzzz, bytesread, bufzzzz.Length - bytesread);
                        bytesread += ii;
                    }

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

                    if (bytesread - bytesbefore > 0)
                        timeout = 0;
                    else
                    {
                        timeout += (int)(DateTime.Now - dt).TotalMilliseconds;
                    }
                    if (bytesread > 5)
                        if (timeout > _ACCUMULATETIMEOUT)
                            break;

                    if (bytesread <= 5)
                        if (timeout > _ACCUMULATETIMEOUT * 2)
                            break;

                    bytesbefore = bytesread;
                }
                WorkOnReceiveModemData(buf.Take(bytesread).ToArray());

                x.BeginRead(buf, bytesread, buf.Length, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveDataAsync), (object)x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Maybe i have made mistake, but in the second version it read (right):
0x00 0x10 0x3F 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFD 0xFC

But in the first version it read:

Read: 0x00 0x10 0x3F 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFD 0xFC 0x00 0x10 0x3F 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFD 0xFC

or:

Read:  0x10 0x3F 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFD 0xFC

Read:  0x00 0x10 0x3F 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFD 0xFC

Read:  0x00 0x10 0x3F 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0xFD 0xFC

My clients are a different GPRS Modems. I hope smb can help me.

Comment: I do not know why but ReadAsync version of Server is reading this packet many times. But in BeginRead, EndRead version of Server read packet and NetworkStream is clean and waiting my asker packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry.  It is work equal, but ReadAsync more faster on my opinion and more clearer. I haved mistake in other code, i every time sent twice packet to GPRS modem, and the modem make compile two answer in one.

At the beginer i had to different server, when i change ReadAsync on (BeginRead, EndRead) i saw the same mistake. And found it.